# Integrating cross products

Tags: vectors, conventions

I know that while integrating dot product to two vector quantities along a line integral, the limits of the integration implicitly takes care of the direction in which we integrate from [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/476912/direction-of-d-mathbfl) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/443988/why-does-this-line-integral-give-the-wrong-sign).

But would this be true in case of cross products? Would the limits of the line integral of a cross product implicitly take care of the direction?

Comment: Can you write the expression for cross-product (integral one which you are talking about)?

Comment: @YoungKindaichi , It's a hypothetical question. I have not been able to think of an example yet.

Comment: an example could be the rotational work done by an electric field on an electric dipole:$work = \int T d\Theta = \int ( \vec{p} \:\:\mathbf{x}\:\: \vec{E} )\:\:d\Theta $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, limits on an integral over a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ implicitly take care of integration direction. (The case $n=1$ is familiar; if $a<b$ the directions for $\int_a^bfdx,\,\int_b^afdx$ are obvious.) It doesn't matter whether what's integrated is a univariate dot product, a $3$-dimensional cross product or in general a $k$-dimensional integrand, viz. $(\int_SVd^nx)_i=\int_SV_id^nx$ for $1\le i\le k$.